# Confused about key error in python script that actually works

Tags: json, python-3.7

I'v got this code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://epistat.sciensano.be/Data/COVID19BE_CASES_MUNI_CUM.json"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = r.json()
for k in cont:
    value =  k.get('CASES') 
    if k ['TX_DESCR_NL'] == 'Wevelgem':
         print('Cases:'+ value)
```

output:

```
Cases:227
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if k ['TX_DESCR_NL'] == 'Wevelgem':
KeyError: 'TX_DESCR_NL'
```

Why i get this KeyError since the script works?

Answer (score 0):

A simple try/catch condition revealed that the 581 element in the list doesn't have the key 'TX_DESCR_NL'.

You wanna check if the key exists first and if it's equal to the value.

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://epistat.sciensano.be/Data/COVID19BE_CASES_MUNI_CUM.json"
r = requests.get(url)
cont = r.json()
for k in cont:
    value =  k.get('CASES') 
    if 'TX_DESCR_NL' in k and k['TX_DESCR_NL'] == 'Wevelgem':
         print('Cases:'+ value)
```